# añadir elementos con np.insert a un np.array vacío

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

estoy con un ejercicio donde tengo que añadir a un np.array vacío los elementos mayores en una primera columna y los menores en una segunda columna de un np.array anteriomente creado. He hecho esto

```
       maximo=0
       minimo=100.
       d=np.empty(10)
       for x in C:
                  if x>maximo:
                     maximo=x
          d.insert(C,0,maximo)
      elif x<minimo:
          minimo=x
          d.insert(C,1,minimo)
  print(d)
```

y me da este error

```
 ValueError                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-89-1f1f6addaee9> in <module>
       5 d=np.empty(10)
       6 for x in C:
 ----> 7     if x>maximo:
       8         maximo=x
       9         d.insert(C,0,maximo)

 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() 
 or a.all()
```

Si alguien me echa una mano se lo agradezco

Comment: No está mal indentado, la página la ha puesto así

Comment: El error es claro, una condición lógica que involucre un array es ambigua: `if x>maximo`, imagina que estás haciendo algo como esto `if [4,6] > 5`  , ¿Qué es lo que buscas con esto? ¿Qué representa `x`?

Comment: Entonces como saco los valores mayores y menores de cada fila del array????

Comment: Estoy agobiado, tengo que entregar mañana unos ejercicios y no soy capaz de ver los fallos, éste en concreto creo que la forma es con np.append, pero no encuentro información de como rellenar un np.array vacío, si es que existe, lo estoy intentando con np.empty pero no lo consigo

Comment: for x in C:
         Z=np.array(x.max())
         V=np.array(x.min())

Comment: Con este for el np.array resultante me da dimensión 0 y no entiendo el por qué